# Just need to check that my understanding is correct.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to learn some algebra to prepare myself for graduate school.

I am doing the problem from *The fundamental Theorem of Algebra* by Benjamin Fine & Gerhard Rosenberger.  Don't worry I am not doing homework.

> Problem 2.5: Let $w^3=1$, $w \neq1$. Show then that $1+w+w^2=0$.

That was very easy.
My question is about $w^3=1,w\neq1$ does that map to $C_3$.

because w would generate the group? by the fact that its not the identity?

Comment: We are not worried with people doing their homework _on their own_; we are only worried about their posting it here and getting us to write out full solution showing all steps. In fact, we will be glad if people did their homeworks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. Indeed, for any $n$, the set of $\zeta \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfying $\zeta^n=1$ form a cyclic group of order $n$ called the group of $n^{th}$ roots of unity. But we can't pick any $\zeta \ne 1$ as a generator in general; for example in the case $n = 4$, $-1$ certainly satisfies $(-1)^4 = 1$, but it only generates a group of order 2. A generator of one of these groups goes by the term "primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity".

Comment: I am unfamiliar with $\zeta$ outside of the use for Riemann zeta function.  Just for clarity, you are using $\zeta$ as a variable？ Similar to $x\in X$ where x  ($\zeta$) is an element within the set X ($\mathbb{C}$)?

Comment: @MaoYiyi: Here, $\zeta$ denotes a complex number such that $\zeta^n=1$.

Comment: @FortuonPaendrag thanks, I thought so, but I am don't know the accepted usages of all the Greek letters, yet.